# Magento 2.2.4: What is "You can now deploy static content on demand while in production mode"?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.4

While reading through the release notes for Magento 2.2.4 ([devdocs.magento.com](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.4CE.html)) I found the following: "You can now deploy static content on demand while in production mode".

Does anyone know what was changed with this? There's no reference to a pull request nor can I find anything changed in the documentation ([devdocs.magento.com](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously, magento would automatically deploy static content in `default` and `developer` modes only. For example when you would try to deploy content in developer mode, you would see:

```
Manual static content deployment is not required in "default" and "developer" modes.
In "default" and "developer" modes static contents are being deployed automatically on demand.
```

This has now extended to production mode which is a welcome change!